# Set the surface view border color

Tags: android

I want to set the surface view border color. When i set this this surface view color then it cover entire by that color. It hide my video which run in the surface view.

```
surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
surfaceView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

I tried this also

```
surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context) {
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        Rect border = new Rect(20, 20, surfaceView.getWidth() - 20, surfaceView.getHeight() - 20);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        canvas.drawRect(border, paint);
    }
};
surfaceView.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
```

I tried this also but still its there is no border on it.

Please help me to set the surface view border color.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);` in your surface view? The Canvas itself shouldn't cover the padding area and therefor you have your border.

Other solution would be to draw the border yourself:

```
// untested - written out of memory
onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    Rect border = new Rect(10, 10, width - 10, height - 10);
    mPaint.setLineWidth(10);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    canvas.drawRect(border, mPaint);
    // draw more...
}
```

**Edit**

in the glorious chat the OP revealed that he uses the SurfaceView to draw a video on it. I suggested to change padding to margin and make the background of the parent view in MAGENTA.

The SurfaceView will be overdrawn completely by the video, therefor the above solution will not work with a video playback.

To sum it up: The OP wasted my time by not providing all necessary information. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this "holder = surfaceView.getHolder();
   Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
   canvas.drawColor(Color.RED);". but its still not working.

Comment: I tried this also.. but no success..surfaceView = new SurfaceView(context) {
      @Override
         protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
       canvas.drawColor(Color.MAGENTA);
          Rect border = new Rect(20, 20, surfaceView.getWidth() - 20, surfaceView.getHeight() - 20);
          Paint paint = new Paint();
          paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
          paint.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
          canvas.drawRect(border, paint);
         }
     };
     surfaceView.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);

Comment: Please put the code in your question and be more clear. "no success" means what?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please go through it. I mean "no success" when i use that code for setting the border color then still there is no border on the surface view.

Comment: You draw MAGENTA twice... make the first to BLACK and it should work.

Comment: Still have same issue. I set the Black to first and second to Magenta

Comment: try to set the style to stroke: `paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32739/discussion-between-android-and-warrenfaith)

Comment: Please explain this Use margin and draw the backend of the parent view in magenta

Comment: This is sooo simple: Layout with background color. In the layout your SurfaceView with margins of 20 or 50 or what ever. Done.